# Bind Picker to list of Picker.Item in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm sure there is a way to do this, but I just can't see how yet.

What I'd like to do, is add a Picker component, but rather than hard-code the list of items, fetch this from a service and have the Picker bound to something I can populate later.

Here's what I have, but my app won't even run now. Any ideas please?

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    Picker,
    Text,
    View
} = React;

var AvailableServices = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        var fetchServicesUri = 'http://some.url/available_services';
        fetch(fetchServicesUri)
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                console.log(responseJson);
                var services = [];
                for(var service in responseJson.services) {
                    services.push(<Picker.Item label={service.Label} value={service.Value}/>);
                }
                this.setState({
                    services: services
                });
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.warn(error);
            })
            .done();
        return {
            services: [],
            selectedService: null
        }
    },

    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Pick a service</Text>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.selectedService}
                    onValueChange={(service) => this.setState({selectedService:service})}
                >
                    {this.state.services}
                </Picker>
            </View>
        );
    }
});

module.exports = AvailableServices;
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You should probably set up your initial state as the empty array, then call your service on componentWillMount or componentDidMount. I've set up something that works with some dummy data [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/pfb6kg), and pasted the code below.

```
'use strict';
var React = require('react-native');
var {
    Picker,
    Text,
    View,
      AppRegistry
} = React;

var PickerItem = Picker.Item;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
    getInitialState() {
        return {
            services: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
            selectedService: 'a'
        }
    },

    componentDidMount() {
        setTimeout(() =>  { 
         this.setState({
          services: [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' ]
         }) 
        }, 3000)
    },

    render() {
        let serviceItems = this.state.services.map( (s, i) => {
            return <Picker.Item key={i} value={s} label={s} />
        });

        return (
            <View>
                <Text>Pick a service</Text>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.selectedService}
                    onValueChange={ (service) => ( this.setState({selectedService:service}) ) } >

                    {serviceItems}

                </Picker>
            </View>
        );
    }
});


AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer - I've tried it out and definitely getting a lot further. I now get this error: "TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.state.services.map')". It's some issue with parsing the returned JSON from the service call to an object. If I try with your example and use some hard-coded chars it works just fine. Thanks!

Comment: @Michael were you calling .map on an array?

Comment: Can I ask what PickerItem is used for?  I don't see it referenced anywhere.  (I'm new to RN and trying to understand.)

Comment: I fixed the map error by writing my own loop `const srvItems = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < this.state.service.length; i++) {
            s = this.state.service[i];
            srvItems.push(<Picker.Item key={i} value={s} label={s} />);
        }` and then writing `{srvItems}` inside the picker. Then works like a bliss.

Comment: Thanks :) It helps me in resolving my issue.

Answer (score 9):

**IMPORTANT**: if you try to iterate an array of numbers with `map` then don't forget that **`label` property of `Picker.Item` should be converted to string**:

```
const pickerItems = [1,2,3].map(i => (
      <Picker.Item label={i.toString()} value={i} />
));
```

Answer (score 7):

No Loops required, here how i did in my react native based project, similar to above answer to bind or add data dynamically in `Picker`

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Picker,View} from 'react-native';
export default class SampleApp extends Component  {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        // HARD CODED DATA , YOU CAN REPLACE THIS DATA  WITH API CALL DATA IN ComponentDidMount() 
       //or in Constructor because countryData is not state.
        this.countryData = ["India","Pakistan","USA"];
        // STATE    
        this.state({
            selectedCountry : null
        });
    }
    // Our country list generator for picker
    countryList = () =>{
        return( this.countryData.map( (x,i) => { 
              return( <Picker.Item label={x} key={i} value={x}  />)} ));
    }
    // RENDER
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <Picker
                    selectedValue={this.state.selectedCountry}
                    onValueChange={ (value) => ( this.setState({selectedCountry : value}) )}>
                    { this.countryList() }
                </Picker>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

> Hope you find my example simple to understand ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can try this one.

```
<Picker
      selectedValue={this.state.facilityId}
      style={{ width: '100%' }}
      onValueChange={(itemValue) => this.setState({ facilityId: itemValue, facilityPicked: true })}>
      {facilities.map((facility, i) => {
        return <Picker.Item key={i} value={facility.id} label={facility.facility_name} />
      })}
</Picker>
```

Here, facilities is a list of object having id and facility_name as key.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. The problem is not with picker but instead, with your code.

```
let items = props.category.map((item,index) => {
     return ( <Picker.Item key={index} label={item.category} value={item.category} /> )
   })
  return(
         <Picker style={styles.pickerStyle}>{items}</Picker>
        );
```

Instead of using `item.category`, i was using `item.name` which caused my app to stop.
So check the value of your data.

Answer (score 0):

Question:

I am using map which is a data structure introduced in JS in ES6.

I am using Picker for the dropdown.
here's my code :

```
<Picker
            selectedValue={this.state.branch}
            style={styles.fieldPicker}
            mode="dropdown"

            onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
              this.setState({branch: itemValue})
            }>

            {/* Data Binding */}

                {this.state.branchData.forEach((name, id) => 
                      {
                      return <Picker.Item key={id} value={id} label={name} />;
                      })
                }



          </Picker>
```

I checked if name and id are being correctly accessed by logging it.
The issue is that I am not able to see the dropdown getting populated.