# How to set state key value pair dynamically in react native?

Tags: react-native

I am developing an ecommerce app where i need to show product options like Size, color etc.

These options are coming dynamically from API.

I am using Picker component of react native to show option values so that user can choose a value.

[image]

Now issue is i select a value, it does not reflect in picker value because i don't know that how to define state variables for pickers dynamically.

so that i can update state values when picker onchangevalue is called.

Initially state looks like this:

```
state = {
        options: {}
    }
```

Now i want that this should dynamically add options to this blank object so it will look like this:

```
state = {
        options: {
            Size: '0.5"',
            Colour: 'White Dudhiya'
        }
    }
```

And after I'll create it then How to access these state variables in any other function.

Please correct me if i am moving in wrong direction and share the correct way to achieve the same.

Please let me know if you need more information from my side.

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

**Edit:**

This is how i am rendering product options and their values dynamically:

```
renderOptions(data) {

        if (data.options.length > 0) {
            var allOptions = data.options.map((item) => {
                if (item.product_option_value.length > 0) {
                    return (
                        <View key={item.option_id} style={{ marginLeft: 10, marginRight: 10, marginBottom: 15, width: windowWidth - 20 }}>
                            <MyAppText>{item.name}</MyAppText>
                            <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, borderColor: '#E8E8E8', marginTop: 5, height: 50 }}>
                                <Picker
                                    selectedValue={this.state.options[item.name]}
                                    style={{ height: 50, width: '100%' }}
                                    onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => 
                                        this.setState(() => {
                                            key = item.name;
                                            return {key: itemValue};
                                        })
                                    }
                                    >
                                        {this.renderOptionValues(item)}
                                </Picker>
                            </View>

                        </View>
                    );
                } else {
                    return;
                }
            });
            return allOptions;
        }
    }

renderOptionValues(option) {
        if (option.product_option_value.length > 0) {
            return (option.product_option_value.map((optionValue) => {
                return (
                    <Picker.Item key={optionValue.option_value_id} label={entities.decode(optionValue.name)} value={optionValue.option_value_id} />
                );
            }));
        }

    }
```

I call renderOptions() function inside my render() function.

Comment: You can use `bracket notation` to set `state` key dynamically. Can you please share how you are iterating over the options and showing them in dropdown?

Comment: Thanks Prasul for replying, can you please share any sample code that how can i use bracket notation to set state. Also I've edited my question and added that how i am iterating over the options.

Comment: You are almost there, just change the `return` statement of `onValueChange` to `return { [key]: itemValue }`, it should work!

Comment: I've changed return statement in same way you shared but still i am not able to set the selected value in picker. It's not updating picker's value and also it is not setting the state's value for the picker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following implementation, I just tried with some hypothetical values and it worked fine.

```js
class DynamicOptions extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {};
  }

  renderOptions = (options = []) => {
    return options.map(option => {
      return <Picker.Item label={option.label} value={option.value} key={option.key}/>
    });
  }

  render() {
    const {
      options
    } = this.props;
    console.log(this.state);
    return ( <
      View style = {{ flex: 1 }} >
      {
        options.map((item, index) => {
          return (
      <View style={{flex: 1}}>
        {
          options.map((item, index) => {
            return (
              <View key={`item-${index}`}>
                <Text>{item.name}</Text>
                <Picker
                  selectedValue={this.state[item.name]}
                  style={{ height: 50, width: '100%' }}
                  onValueChange={(listItem, index) => {
                    this.setState({
                      [item.name]: listItem
                    });
                  }}
                >
                  { this.renderOptions(item.options) }
                </Picker>
              </View>
            )
          })
        }
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default DynamicOptions;
```

Following data I have used to render options (I am not sure what data you are using)

```
const options = [
  {
    name: 'Color',
    options: [{label: 'Red', value: 'Red', key: 'Red'}, {label: 'Green', value: 'Green', key: 'Green'}]
  },
  {
    name: 'Size',
    options: [{label: '1', value: '1', key: '1'}, {label: '2', value: '2', key: '2'}]
  }

];
```

This is how I have called that function

```
<DynamicOptions options={options}/>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: Thanks Prasul for your answer with code sample, I've implemented the same and it worked. I created a separate component as you shared and it is showing everything correctly. Really thanks for your help.

Comment: But just want to know that why you used map() two times with options, i think there should be only two map() funcitons, one for outer options and second for option values. Please correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I've changed my code according to your answer and it is working quite fine. Thanks a ton for your help.

Comment: Glad that it worked, Yes you are right, I have used `map` two times only, once for outer options and another for each item in the picker. Although names (`options`) are same that might be confusing you.

Answer (score 0):

according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/35398253/2083099 , I believe you need something like this,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, FlatList, Image, TouchableOpacity, Dimensions, Picker } from 'react-native';

export default class Test extends Component {
 constructor() {
  super();
   this.state = {
        services: [],
        selectedService: 'a'
  }
 }

componentDidMount() {
//replace api request instead of setTimeout and then change the services data with setState
setTimeout(() =>  { 
 this.setState({
  services: [ 'one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five' ]
  }) 
 }, 3000)
}

render() {
  return (
   <View>
    <Text>Pick a service</Text>
    <Picker
      selectedValue={this.state.selectedService}
      onValueChange={(service) => (this.setState({ selectedService: service }))} >
      {this.state.services.map((s, i) => {
        return <Picker.Item key={i} value={s} label={s} />
      })}
    </Picker>
  </View>
);
}
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nima for your reply, but here you can see that you have a pre-defined array for services and also has a separate variable to hold the value of selected service. But problem is that i don't know how many options will be there so can't use the above approach. I've edited my answer to show how i am iterating over the product options and showing them as pickers.